# D3. Data issues

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Translate(NaN,NaN). In v4:

```
var bubble = d3.pack()
    .size([diameter, diameter])
    .padding(2);
var root = d3.hierarchy({"children": data.values})
console.log(bubble(root).children);
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
              .data(bubble(root).children)
              .enter().append("g")
              .attr("class", "node")
              .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")"; });
```

In v3 correctly:

```
var bubble = d3.layout.pack()
               .sort(null)
               .size([diameter, diameter])
               .padding(2);
var root = {"children": data.values}
console.log(bubble.nodes(root).children);
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
              .data(bubble.nodes(root)
              .filter(function (d) { return !d.children; }))
              .enter().append("g")
              .attr("class", "node")
              .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
```

In v3 console, "r" have a value. But in v4 not. I think it's problem with data import.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For having the `x`, `y` and `r` properties, you'll have to pass a function to `sum()` in `d3.hierarchy()`.

According to the [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/blob/master/README.md#node_sum):

> You must call node.sum or node.count before invoking a hierarchical layout that requires node.value

As I don't know the structure of your data, I created this dummy array:

```
var data = {
    children: [{
        name: "foo",
        size: 50
    }, {
        name: "bar",
        size: 20
    }, {
        name: "baz",
        size: 40
    }]
};
```

Here is your code using `sum()`, check the console:

```js
var data = {
    children: [{
        name: "foo",
        size: 50
    }, {
        name: "bar",
        size: 20
    }, {
        name: "baz",
        size: 40
    }]
};

var diameter = 500;

var bubble = d3.pack()
    .size([diameter, diameter])
    .padding(2);

var root = d3.hierarchy(data)
    .sum(function(d) {
        return d.size;
    });;

console.log(bubble(root).children);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```